# How can I select from a SQL DB using linq and EF where ExpiryDate is 30 days to expire from today using DateDiff function

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to get items from SQL db using EF and Linq where the membership date expires (this date is already predetermined in the db), I want to get Items where the expiration date is in 30 days from today using the `DateDiff` function in C#, how can I do this I am still new to C#, here is what I have so far.

```
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    // this is where I want to filter the list to get only members with an
    // expiration date is 30 days from today
    List<Membership> membership = db.Membership.Where(m => m.ExpiryDate... 

    foreach(var member in members)
    {
        DoWork();
    }
}
```

Then from here I do what else I need, any help with archieving this kind of filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply pre-compute in C# the desired value and do in SQL a simple comparison:

```
var expiryDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30);
var memberships = db.Membership.Where(m => m.ExpiryDate > expiryDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var membership = db.Memberships.Where(m => SqlFunctions.DateDiff(m.ExpiryDate, /*[other parameters]*/))
```

Make sure you don't use methods in other parameters. If you need DateTime.Today.AddDays(30) declare it as a variable before using it in linq to entities.

However, based on your questions I don't think you really need the DateDiff function. You need only to compare the ExpiryDate with targetDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30) in your linq to entities query.